# MySQL значение по умолчанию + 1

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дано: есть INT поле с неуникальными значениями.

Можно ли как то вписать определение по умолчанию (см картинку), чтоб при добавлении записи в таблицу туда автоматом вписывалось **максимальное значение +1** ?

Допустим , если там значения 1, 2 , 0 , 0 , 3 , 0, то туда бы вписалось 4.

Спасибо

---

### конкретный пример

есть таблица с записями, часть записей помечаются как тестовые и им присваивается индекс - 0 (не primary).
Выглядит это так

id (primary)  |  report_id

```
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 0
5 | 4
6 | 0
```

Вот надо сделать так, чтоб при добавлении следующей записи  во втором столбце нарисовалась пятерка

Comment: Может сюда можно вписать хранимую функцию, которая будет вызываться при добавлении и высчитывать цифру?

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя.
Такой функционал доступен для полей с атрибутом auto_increment, но такое поле должно быть только одно на таблицу и не может содержать неуникальные значения.

Надо всегда задавать вопрос не про частную проблему при изобретении своего велосипеда, а про конкретную проблему, для которой ищется решение. то есть не "как к дефолтному значению прибавить 1", а "мне нужно разместить такое-то поле для того-то". Обычно решение оказывается куда проще, чем кажется.

Если этот id относится к самой таблице, то сделать автоинкремент + поле, в котором пишется "нулевость" строки.
А если относится к другой таблице, то так делать не надо вообще.

Как я и писал выше, надо не выдумывать отсебятину с крестиками и ноликами, а выдавать тестовым записям обычный автоинкрементный айди, плюс добавить в таблицу булево поле для обозначения тестовых записей. 
А то поле, которое сейчас праймари, сделать просто уникальным.

### Очень Важное Замечание

**Идентификаторы записей к нумерации не имеют ни малейшего отношения. Вообще никакого. От слова "совсем".**
Если хочется пронумеровать вывод, то это делается в РНР, на лету, тем самым прибавлением единички к переменной, выводимой на каждой строке. Хранить же нумерацию в БД нет смысла, посольку выборки всегда разные и для каждой потребуется своя.

Comment: Это и есть конкретная задача. Есть существующая таблица, в которую добавляется это поле. Если в поле не передается 0 - то там должна быть цифра на 1 больше, чем максимум.
primary index уже есть

Comment: Не совсем так. Пример вынес в сам вопрос

Comment: Это надо для того, чтоб в выводе отчета шла нумерация записей из второго поля, тобишь без учета тестовых и юзер увидел нумерацию не  1, 2, 4, 6 из первого поля, а 1,2,3,4

Comment: **очень важное дополнение**: Мне надо отобразить строку из примера с праймари индексом 5 (но при этом в отчете должна быть 4.) Мне это средствами пхп как делать прикажете ? ВЫбрать все записи и от индекса отнять те , которые помечены как тестовые ?

Comment: @volkoff это можно сделать и в php и в sql, на лету (решение искать либо в гугле, либо задав другой вопрос). Ответьте для себя на вопрос, что будет если вам надо будет поменять порядок или удалить "не тестовую" запись, добавится ли у вас проблема "как перенумеровать записи?"

Comment: @YuraIvanov ничего преноситься/удаляться не будет. Решение и так есть - навскидку - держать где то в таблице с конфигом индекс максимальный и при каждой записи его на 1 увеличивать и это значение вставлять. Просто думал, это можно как то решить способом, про который спрашивал